# applying skip connections for pre-trained vgg19 in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use VGG19 as an encoder in  convolutional LSTM autoencoder structure, i want to apply skip connections similarly in UNet between the last convolutional layer of each block in VGG19 to my decoder ( which has a similar architecture with the VGG19, just upsampling instead of max pooling).

Since the inputs are time dependent, i wrapped the VGG19 with a timedistributed layer.

But however, when i initalized my model, i have a graph disconnection error.

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

My code is as follows:

```
def build_lstm(inputs,lstm_h_dim):
lstm_cell = MultiRNNCell([LSTMCell(h_dim, forget_bias=1.0) for h_dim in lstm_h_dim], state_is_tuple=True)
x = RNN(lstm_cell,unroll = True,return_sequences = True,time_major = False)(inputs)
return x



def build_decoder(inputs,skip_1,skip_2,skip_3,skip_4,skip_5):
    conv_size = 512
    ## 1st conv block
    # inputs = keras.Input((self.compressed_dim,self.compressed_dim,self.conv_size))
    x = TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2)))(inputs)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Add())([skip_1,x])
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2)))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    ### 2nd conv block
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Add())([skip_2,x])
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)    
    x = TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2)))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    ## 3rd conv block
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//2,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Add())([skip_3,x])
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//2,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//2,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//2,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2)))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//4,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Add())([skip_4,x])
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//4,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2)))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    ## 4th conv block
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//8,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Add())([skip_5,x])
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters = conv_size//8,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'))(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters =3,kernel_size = 3,padding = 'same',activation = 'sigmoid'))(x)
    # decoder_model = Model([inputs,encoder.inputs],x)
    return x
    
def build_res_vgg(batch_size,seq_length):
    rnn_size = 512
    seq_length = seq_length
    conv_size = 512
    compressed_dim = 7
    img_dim = (224,224)
    encoder_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet',include_top =False)
    # vgg_outputs = [encoder_model.layers[i].output for i in range(len(encoder_model.layers))]
    time_series_input = keras.Input(shape = (seq_length-1,img_dim[0],img_dim[1],3),batch_size = batch_size)
    encoder = Model(inputs = encoder_model.input,outputs = encoder_model.get_layer('block5_pool').output)

    time_wrapped_output = TimeDistributed(encoder)(time_series_input)
    

    # encoder = Model(inputs = encoder_model.input,outputs = vgg_outputs)
    # time_series_model = []
    # for out in encoder.output:
    #     time_series_model.append(layers.Wrapper(TimeDistributed(Model(encoder.input,out)))(time_series_input))
    time_encoder = Model(inputs = time_series_input,outputs = time_wrapped_output)
    
    encoder_output = TimeDistributed(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (7,7)))(time_encoder.output)
    encoder_output = layers.Reshape(target_shape = (seq_length-1,conv_size))(encoder_output)

    encoder_model.trainable = False
    skip_1 = encoder.layers[20].output
    skip_2 = encoder.layers[15].output
    skip_3 = encoder.layers[10].output
    skip_4 = encoder.layers[5].output
    skip_5 = encoder.layers[2].output
    lstm_h_dim = [512,512,512]

    # lstm_inputs = keras.Input(shape = (seq_length-1,conv_size),batch_size = batch_size)

    # encoded_img = SequentialEncoder(seq_length,batch_size,encoder)(encoder.input)
    lstm_input = LSTM_VAR(rnn_size,rnn_size)(encoder_output,activation = 'relu')
    lstm_output = build_lstm(lstm_input,lstm_h_dim)
    lstm_output = LSTM_VAR(rnn_size,rnn_size)(lstm_output)
    lstm_output = LSTM_VAR(rnn_size,rnn_size/2)(lstm_output)
    lstm_output = LSTM_VAR(rnn_size/2,rnn_size//4)(lstm_output)
    bottleneck = TimeDistributed(Dense(7*7*conv_size,activation = 'relu'))(lstm_output)
    bottleneck = layers.Reshape(target_shape = (seq_length-1,compressed_dim,compressed_dim,conv_size))(bottleneck)
    # decoded_img = SequentialDecoder(seq_length,batch_size,self.build_decoder(bottleneck,skip_1,skip_2,skip_3,skip_4,skip_5),compressed_dim)
    decoded_img = build_decoder(bottleneck,skip_1,skip_2,skip_3,skip_4,skip_5)

    lstm_model = Model(inputs = [time_encoder.inputs],outputs = decoded_img)

    return lstm_model

class LSTM_VAR(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,input_size,output_size):
        super(LSTM_VAR,self).__init__()
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([int(input_size), int(output_size)]),trainable=True)
        self.B = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([int(output_size)]),trainable=True)
    
    def call(self,inputs,activation = None):
        if activation == 'relu':
            output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs,self.W)+self.B) 
        else:
            output = tf.matmul(inputs,self.W)+self.B
        return output
```

The issue happens in the `build_res_vgg` function. When i call the Model API.

It seems to only work if i include 2 inputs in the lstm_model, however i should only have 1 input, input shape of (batch size, timestep, img_h,img_w,3), it is suppose to go through the vgg19 encoder, lstm layers then get reconstructed back to the same image.

Answer (score 0):

*Graph disconnected* means that you did not configure your model correctly so that the **TensorFlow can not find a connected path between your input and output layer**.

If you examine your path from inputs and outputs, you will find out that in your `Add` layers you have added layers from the encoder which are another input to your decoder besides your original decoder input. So, you should add all of them to your model inputs, or you can simply add your encoder model input to your inputs like this:

```
decoder_model = Model([inputs, self.encoder_model.input],outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is able to initalized, however, it requires 2 inputs when i call the model, however, i only have a single input to passed it in, i edited the question.